# Leetcode 686 Repeated String Match Having Trouble Understanding the Explanation

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, modulo

I am having trouble understanding why the solution of Leetcode's Repeated String match only goes up to q + 1 repeats of A (if A.length() < B.length()) for B to be a possible substring of A repeated.

I read other StackOverflow solutions as well as Leetcode discussion pages but I am still unable to fully understand the solution.

The algorithm is explained as:

```
Imagine we wrote S = A+A+A+.... If B is to be a substring of S, we 
only need to check whether some S[0:], S[1:], ..., S[len(A) - 1:] 
starts with B, as S is long enough to contain B, and S has period 
at most len(A).

Now, suppose q is the least number for which len(B) <= len(A * q). 
We only need to check whether B is a substring of A * q or A * 
(q+1). If we try k < q, then B has larger length than A * q and 
therefore can't be a substring. When k = q+1, A * k is already big 
enough to try all positions for B; namely, A[i:i+len(B)] == B for i 
= 0, 1, ..., len(A) - 1.
```

The implementation is as follows:

```
class Solution {
  public int repeatedStringMatch(String A, String B) {
      int q = 1;
      StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder(A);
      for (; S.length() < B.length(); q++) S.append(A);
      if (S.indexOf(B) >= 0) return q;
      if (S.append(A).indexOf(B) >= 0) return q+1;
      return -1;
  }
}
```

I understand that when A.length() < B.length(), B cannot be a substring, so we would need to keep appending A until A.length() is at least equal to B.length(). But once this is the case, why is it that we would only need to add one more copy of A to get the minimum number of repeats?

My intuition is that after A is repeated some number of times there is a pattern that is established and if B does not fall into that pattern/sequence of characters then no matter how many times you repeat A, B will not be a substring of the repeated A.

However,  I just don't know why it has to be specifically the number of copies to match B's length or 1 more copy added after A.length() = B.length().

If someone could clear up this confusion for me, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have pretty much understand most of it,
so lets you go with another basic example.

```
ampleex
itsalreadyhereexample
exam
```

Lets say B is `example` and A is one of the above.

---

For the first case A.length() == B.length()
we check whether it is a substring and get no as an answer.
So we add it once more and get 'ampleexampleex'
and now we get the result that A contains B.

---

For the second case A.length() > B.length()
we check whether it is a substring and get the result that A contains B.

(If it would not be here we still wound need check if its in the repeated from,
which is equivalent to the first case)

---

For the third case A.length() < B.length
so we repeat it till we cover the length of B
and get `examexam`.

We see that its not in there, so we add it once more,
and its still not in there (`examexamexam`).

---

The reason we need to do that, is because it could be a more special case.
B coud be somthing like `xamexame` - basically a repetition
of one of As variations.

(Possible variations in this case would be repetitions of `xame`, `amex`, `mexa`.)

In this case it must be in a repeated form that is longer than B,
which is where the q+1 comes from.

Lets look at the repetions in more detail:
B`s length can be at most (A.length()*q)+x, where x is [0, A.length].

```
A = exam
B = xame[xame]
```

B is still a repition of A, but every character in the last repition is optional.

```
examexam
 xame
 xamex
 xamexa
 xamexam

examexamexam
 xamexame
```

Adding another `exam` to S, won`t change anything since we covered all possibities allready (no new pattern will appear from now on).

If its not in there it can`t be a repition. The other scenarions - where
it could be a substring - have been covered by the first and second case.

---

I hope going through this example helps you clear your confusion. 
If not just ask what point you don`t understand.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I get the special case where the beginning of A could be appended to the end of A and make B; however, my main point of confusion is why are we allowed to stop at q+1? What is it about going past q+1 that causes the redundancy? And how would I intuit that going forward?

Comment: I assume you don`t have a problem with case 1 & 2, so I only added more details for the 3rd case.